# Problema al momento de encontrar mi tabla en visual studio comunity

Tags: c#, sql, visual

Estoy haciendo un proceso ETL y al momento de conectarme con la tabla de mi base de datos no me aparece [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya probé con autenticación de Windows y nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

inclusive está ahi mi base de datos en sql no se que sucede

Comment: Presiona "Probar conexión" en el botón de abajo y luego comenta el resultado

Comment: TÍTULO: Administrador de conexiones
------------------------------

No se pudo realizar la conexión de prueba debido a un error al inicializar el proveedor. La clave proporcionada no se encontró en el diccionario.

------------------------------
BOTONES:

Aceptar
------------------------------ Me sale eso pero es raro, si tengo mi contraseña correcta, no se a que se refiere

Comment: O sea está dificil equivocarse en la pass si tiene 2 caracteres

Comment: cambia el OLEDB nativo a SQLClient

Answer (score 0):

Parece un problema de conexión.

- Revisa los permisos para conexiones externas ([explicación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16))
- Que esté como multiusuario ([explicación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver16))
- Que no haya problemas con el firewall ([explicación](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwWyOtQzfsc))
- Que funcione correctamente el DNS.
- Que el servicio de SQL esté activo ([explicación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver16))
- Que no se haya deshabilitado la cuenta sa (lo cual es una buena práctica).

Esos son los problemas más comunes que recuerdo que pueden impedir la conexión, considerando que sí exista la base de datos y la instancia.